# How to get value of a particular xml tag having same names and no attribute while parsing xml in sax parser

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

Actually i was trying to get value of only one particular node but the node tag is at many places in the xml document. here is xml snippet

```
<t:Address xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><t:Name>XYZ Conference Rooms</t:Name><t:EmailAddress>XYZConferenceRooms@abc.co.in</t:EmailAddress><t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType><t:MailboxType>PublicDL</t:MailboxType></t:Address><t:Address xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><t:Name>ABC Conference Rooms</t:Name><t:EmailAddress>ABCConferenceRooms@abc.co.in</t:EmailAddress><t:RoutingType>SMTP</t:RoutingType><t:MailboxType>PublicDL</t:MailboxType></t:Address>
```

The thing is i only want value (ABCConferenceRooms@abc.co.in) from the above xml. The above is just a code snippet we have 10 values of email address in xml.

While i am doing this in my parser

```
    String value;
String url;
String confName;
String confEmail;

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    value = qName;
     confEmail = qName;
     confName = qName;
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {
    if (value.equals("Value")) {
        String OperationName1Text = new String(ch, start, length);
        info.setValue(OperationName1Text);
        Log.d("URL", OperationName1Text);
    }
     else if (confName.equals("t:EmailAddress")) {
     String getEmail = new String(ch, start, length);
     info.setEmail(getEmail);
     Log.d("Email", getEmail);
     }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    value = qName;
    confEmail = qName;
    confName = qName;
}
```

i am only able to display all the email address but i only want one mentioned above. What changes in the code is needed.?

Anyone worked on similar situation can help
Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

As you use the same namespace in both Address nodes they will be inherit to the email nodes as well.So there is no difference in namespaces and you can not find the exact node to get what you want.If you know the position of email node(second email node etc) then you can have a counter in startElement() and when counter finds second email node then get the relevant text in it.

Comment: Thanks Sanjaya.. Will try now and let you know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try SAX XML Parser for your work. If not then try it once ...

your XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff>
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff>
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

JAVA CODE for XML parser

```
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class ReadXMLFile {

   public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {

    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

    DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

    boolean bfname = false;
    boolean blname = false;
    boolean bnname = false;
    boolean bsalary = false;

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("FIRSTNAME")) {
            bfname = true;
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("LASTNAME")) {
            blname = true;
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("NICKNAME")) {
            bnname = true;
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("SALARY")) {
            bsalary = true;
        }

    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
        String qName) throws SAXException {

        System.out.println("End Element :" + qName);

    }

    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

        if (bfname) {
            System.out.println("First Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            bfname = false;
        }

        if (blname) {
            System.out.println("Last Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            blname = false;
        }

        if (bnname) {
            System.out.println("Nick Name : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            bnname = false;
        }

        if (bsalary) {
            System.out.println("Salary : " + new String(ch, start, length));
            bsalary = false;
        }

    }

     };

       saxParser.parse("c:\\file.xml", handler);

     } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }

   }

}
```

your out put is :

```
Start Element :company
Start Element :staff
Start Element :firstname
First Name : yong
End Element :firstname
Start Element :lastname
Last Name : mook kim
End Element :lastname
Start Element :nickname
Nick Name : mkyong
End Element :nickname
Start Element :salary
Salary : 100000
End Element :salary
End Element :staff
Start Element :staff
Start Element :firstname
First Name : low
End Element :firstname
Start Element :lastname
Last Name : yin fong
End Element :lastname
Start Element :nickname
Nick Name : fong fong
End Element :nickname
Start Element :salary
Salary : 200000
End Element :salary
End Element :staff
End Element :company
```

Comment: HI, I tried with SAX parser only as thats the best if you are creating app on android. I have tried the above example also. I know it works but the thing is i only want one value as String and not all. Like to explain from the above example, i would like only (yin fong) to be returned but not mook kim or any other names in the tags. I tried counter also but not sure how to implement. i tried putting  if(counter<10){
    confName = qName;
   }  in start element method but still it gives all the emails

Comment: For that you also implement regex or pattern like if you want to add some specific name with the tag